# How to handle I18n when texts are not in .properties files but in the jsp page itself

Tags: spring-mvc, internationalization

I'm building a multi-languages application with Spring MVC.

So far I handled the multi-languages system with the Spring class `ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource` and .properties files. It was easy since texts were very short.

Now, I have to translate the body of the page and I can't rely on .properties files.

I have an Italian version  of the page and an english version of the page. My doubt is: how should I handle it?

I thought that after the `@Controller` return the page name, for example "index", I should have a filter that check the application `Locale` and then add to the page name a suffix. So, the filter must turn **"index"** into **"it/index"** or **"en/index"**.

IS it a good way to solve the issue?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a suggestion with one drawback: I didn't test it with .jsp but .vm. The idea might still work.

As not to break the i18n mechanism put a message key, say `parseContent` in every language.property file. Now, make a view for every locale and name them, say `parse_en_US.vm`, `parse_de_DE.vm` and so on. These files must only contain what you wouldn't want to be in the language.property files.

Example of an entry in `messages_en_US.porperties` might be `parseContent = parse_en_US.vm`

An now use `#springMessage('parseContent')` to get the right view name depending on the present locale. This view you parse as a sub-view and problem solved.

For .vm it looks like this:

```
#set($view = "#springMessage('parseContent')")
#parse($view)
```

Same number of .vm files, but no need to invent sth new.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I'll try to work on it.